# Unable To work with the Sci-Kit Learn Catagorical Imputer

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am unable to get the required result from the Sci-kit learn categorical Imputer.

```
df_cat = df[["Suburb", "Address", "Type", "Method", "SellerG", "Date", "YearBuilt", "CouncilArea", "Regionname"]]

df_cat['Suburb'] = pd.to_numeric(df_cat['Suburb'], errors='coerce')

df_cat['Address'] = pd.to_numeric(df_cat['Address'], errors='coerce')

df_cat['Type'] = pd.to_numeric(df_cat['Type'], errors='coerce')

df_cat['Method'] = pd.to_numeric(df_cat['Method'], errors='coerce')

df_cat['SellerG'] = pd.to_numeric(df_cat['SellerG'], errors='coerce')

df_cat['YearBuilt'] = pd.to_numeric(df_cat['YearBuilt'], errors='coerce')

df_cat['CouncilArea'] = pd.to_numeric(df_cat['CouncilArea'], errors='coerce')

df_cat['Regionname'] = pd.to_numeric(df_cat['Regionname'], errors='coerce')

df_cat['Date'] = pd.to_numeric(df_cat['Date'], errors='coerce')

from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

imputer2 = Imputer(strategy="most_frequent")

imputer2.fit(df_cat)

imputer2.statistics_
```

Result

```
array([     nan,      nan,      nan,      nan, 1.00e+00,      nan,
       1.97e+03,      nan,      nan])
```

The existing values are getting replaced by NaN. It is doing the exact opposite of my requirement.

Comment: There is no 'categorical' imputer in scikit-learn ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.impute)) (plus you seem to use an old sklearn version).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. I tried using the imputer given in your link. However, I am still getting the same result.

Comment: import numpy as np

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer


imp = SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')


imp.fit(df_cat)


>>>SimpleImputer(copy=True, fill_value=None, missing_values=nan,
       strategy='most_frequent', verbose=0)


imp.transform(df_cat)